# Chaining join method after push doesn't works

Tags: ecmascript-6

```js
let data = {a:5,b:6,c:7,d:8}
let price = 15
let urlParams = Object.entries(data)
                    .map(([key,value])=>`${key}=${value}`)
                    .push("price="+price)
                    .join("&")
```

I need to get the output as a string
**"a=5&b=6&c=7&d=8&price=15"**

The return result of push will be the length of the array, so when i call a join method it will return an error. Is there any work around for this

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. assign `urlParams` to a variable
2. `push` your string onto it
3. then `join("&")`

`Array.push` modifies the array because it is mutating.

Answer (score 1):

Your `push` will mutate the `array` directly and that could potentially lead to error-prone code.

You can use `concat` since it returns a new array.

```js
let data = {a:5,b:6,c:7,d:8}
let price = 15
let urlParams = Object.entries(data)
                    .map(([key,value])=>`${key}=${value}`)
                    .concat("price="+price)
                    .join("&")
console.log(urlParams);
```